# Use jq to merge keys with common id

Tags: json, key, jq

consider a file 'b.json':

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "foo": "cannot be replaced, id isn't in a.json, stay untouched",
    "baz": "do not touch3"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "foo": "should be replaced with 'foo new2'",
    "baz": "do not touch2"
  }
]
```

and 'a.json':

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "foo": "foo new2",
    "baz": "don't care"
  }
]
```

I want to update the key "foo" in b.json using jq with the matching value from a.json. It should also work with more than one entry in a.json.

Thus the desired output is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "foo": "cannot be replaced, id isn't in a.json, stay untouched",
    "baz": "do not touch3"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "foo": "foo new2",
    "baz": "do not touch2"
  }
]
```

Comment: here you go but there isn't anything new. The question already had in it, that "baz" shouldn't be changed

Comment: your question is about generic JSON manipulation, if you like I can provide you with an alternative (non-jq) easy solution.

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you very much but I've only basic tools (grep,sed,sh and jq) on the target machine and can't install additional packages to i'm stuck to jq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one of several possibilities that use `INDEX/2`. If your jq does not have this as a built-in, see below.

```
jq --argfile a a.json '
  INDEX($a[]; .id) as $dict
  | map( (.id|tostring) as $id
         | if ($dict|has($id)) then .foo = $dict[$id].foo 
           else . end)' b.json
```

There are other ways to pass in the contents of a.json and b.json.

### Caveat

The above use of INDEX assumes there are no "collisions", which would happen if, for example, one of the objects has .id equal to 1 and another has .id equal to "1".  If there is a possibility of such a collision, then a more complex definition of INDEX could be used.

### `INDEX/2`

Straight from builtin.jq:

```
def INDEX(stream; idx_expr):
  reduce stream as $row ({}; .[$row|idx_expr|tostring] = $row);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly. It will take some time until I really understand whats happening here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generic answer that makes no assumptions about the values of the .id keys except that they are distinct JSON values.

#### Generalization of INDEX/2

```
def type2: [type, if type == "string" then . else tojson end];

def dictionary(stream; f):
  reduce stream as $s ({}; setpath($s|f|type2; $s));

def lookup(value):
  getpath(value|type2);

def indictionary(value):
  (value|type2) as $t
  | has($t[0]) and (.[$t[0]] | has($t[1]));
```

### Invocation

```
jq --argfile a a.json -f program.jq b.json
```

### main

```
dictionary($a[]; .id) as $dict
| b
| map( .id as $id 
       | if ($dict|indictionary($id)) 
         then .foo = ($dict|lookup($id).foo) 
         else . end)
```