# JSON: Modify specific value based on matched key:value of another JSON

Tags: json, match, jq

I have 2 JSON files and I want to update one of them based on the other. **More specifically, if a specific key:value pair matches between the file, I want to update another (and only 1 other) key:value pair.**

a.json looks as follows:

```
[
{"i":"1234","f":"123","a":"0"},
{"i":"1235","f":"123","a":"0"},
{"i":"1236","f":"123","a":"0"},
{"i":"1237","f":"123","a":"0"},
{"i":"1238","f":"123","a":"0"}
]
```

b.json looks as follows:

```
[
{"i":"1234","f":"555","a":"1"},
{"i":"1235","f":"555","a":"1"},
{"i":"1236","f":"555","a":"1"},
{"i":"1237","f":"555","a":"1"},
{"i":"1238","f":"555","a":"1"}
]
```

I want to update b.json so that if the "i" value of b.json matches the "i" value of a.json, the value for "f" is replaced by a.json's value. I.e. I want b.json to look like this:

```
[
{"i":"1234","f":"123","a":"1"},
{"i":"1235","f":"123","a":"1"},
{"i":"1236","f":"123","a":"1"},
{"i":"1237","f":"123","a":"1"},
{"i":"1238","f":"123","a":"1"}
]
```

So to be clear, **only the f values must be replaced, not the ones for a**.

I have found this partial solution:

**1)** Make a file called update.jq such that:

```
reduce keys[] as $k (.; if $a|has($k) then .[$k] = $a[$k] else . end)
```

**2)** Run:

```
jq --argfile a a.json -f a.jq b.json
```

This gives me this where both f and a have been updated **but I only want f to be updated.** How can I ensure that only f gets updated?

```
[
{"i":"1234","f":"555","a":"0"},
{"i":"1235","f":"555","a":"0"},
{"i":"1236","f":"555","a":"0"},
{"i":"1237","f":"555","a":"0"},
{"i":"1238","f":"555","a":"0"}
]
```

Comment: Just to confirm you are just trying to get the result using jq ?

Comment: take a look at -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60228327/use-jq-to-merge-keys-with-common-id?rq=1 . The problem statement looks similar to yours

Comment: @khari-sing yes I am.

Answer (score 0):

After correcting the input files, the following can be used to achieve the desired result:

```
jq --argfile a a.json -f program.jq b.json
```

where program.jq holds:

```
(INDEX($a[]; .i) | map_values(.f)) as $dict
| map( .f = $dict[.i] )
```